# Getting the error "Expression does not produce a value

Tags: vb.net

I am relatively new to using visual basic and I am having a problem populating a list box from a database. The error that comes up is Expression does not produce a value.

Here is the code from My form:

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Populate Blu Ray and DVD listboxes

    Dim objMovies As New clsMovies

    objMovies.Select_BR_List()
    objMovies.Select_Dvd_List()

    For Each strBluRay As String In objMovies.Select_BR_List
        lstBluRay.Items.Add(strBluRay)
    Next

    For Each strDVD As String In objMovies.Select_Dvd_List
        lstDvd.Items.Add(strDVD)
    Next
End Sub
```

And here's the code from the class:

```
Public Sub Select_Dvd_List()
    Dim objConnection As New SqlCeConnection(mstrCN)

    'Create SQL statement
    mstrSQL = "Select * from Dvd"
    'Instantiate command
    Dim objCommand As New SqlCeCommand(mstrSQL, objConnection)

    'open Database
    objCommand.Connection.Open()

    'Instantiate Data Reader
    Dim objDataReader As SqlCeDataReader

    'Execute SQL
    objDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader()

    'read Sql results
    Do While (objDataReader.Read)
        mlstDvd.Add(objDataReader.Item("dvdTitle").ToString)
    Loop

    'Close 
    objCommand.Dispose()
    objDataReader.Close()
    objDataReader.Dispose()
    objConnection.Close()
    objConnection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please include the full output from the error. Also, is there a reason that you are using SQL CE?

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you're trying to enumerate a Sub.  In VB.NET, methods can either a Sub, which doesn't return a value, or a Function, which does return a value.  Your `Select_Dvd_List` method is a Sub, so it doesn't return a value.  You have this code though:

```
For Each strDVD As String In objMovies.Select_Dvd_List
```

That is trying to loop through the result of `Select_Dvd_List` but, as we've already established, `Select_Dvd_List` has no result.  In that method, you are adding items to `mlstDvd` so surely that loop should be:

```
For Each strDVD As String In objMovies.mlstDvd
```